# Cannot expose private base class member functions in SWIG wrapper

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, swig, private-members

I'm wrapping some C++ code with SWIG for an Android application. I'm facing an issue when I use a class that privately inherit from another, and throw a couple of `using` directive in there to expose some of the parent's member functions. Looks like this:

```
#include "Bar.h"

class Foo : private Bar {

//Stuff Foo-specific...

public:
    using Bar::baz;
};
```

The thing is, when I run SWIG, I get the following message during the wrapping:

> Foo.h:8: Warning 315: Nothing known about 'Bar::baz()'.

Note: Both headers are included in the wrapper file, only the `Foo` header is wrapped, as I don't want the `Bar` header to be wrapped, my `.i` file looks like:

```
%{
    #include "Bar.h"
    #include "Foo.h"
%}

%include "Foo.h"
```

Then, my Java class doesn't compile because it cannot find this symbol...

I read in the SWIG documentation that [private inheritance](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn20) and the [`using` keyword](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn35) (although there isn't an example about private inheritance) are supposed to be supported, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `using` statement should be `using Bar::baz;`.

Anyway, as SWIG says in the warning, it cannot wrap `Foo::baz()` if it does not know the declaration in `Bar::baz()`.

Therefore, you need to show the declaration to SWIG, e.g., by an `%include "Bar.h"` directive. If you do not want `Bar` to be wrapped, you can use an additional `%ignore Bar;` directive.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
%ignore Bar;
%inline %{
class Bar {
public:
  double baz() { return 4.2; }
};
class Foo : private Bar {
public:
  using Bar::baz;
};
%}
```

Comment: Ah, forgot about the `%ignore` directive indeed. I also thought that having the `#include` would be sufficient as it needed only the declaration, but was apparently wrong... Thanks!